# extending an instance of a javascript class and carry the state of that class instance to the child?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, es6-class

I know there are Other ways of doing this, however I am trying to wrap my head around extending a class, from inside an instance of the parent.  I know that I can instantiate directly to the child, however just wondering if I can extend once the parent calls it.

```
class Transaction {
    constructor(action, color, amount, username) {
        this.action = action
        this.color = color
        this.sender = sender
        this.receiver = receiver
        this.amount = amount
    }
    setup(){
        // does some stuff to determine what we need 
        // to do after we store the entry to the db
        
        await this.dbEntry()
        
        // based on the info generated above extend this instance that already has some calculations made to it... 
    }
    async dbEntry(){
        // stores entry to the db
    }

}

class Purchase extends Transaction{}
```

Esentially Some things are universal -> somethings are going to be determined down the line based on a chain of events, Is it possible to carry the state of the instance over from parent to child, not just the constructor functions.

I havent been able to think of how I would call it. And if it is going to cary the data that i need over.

Comment: It's unclear what you really mean here.  If you want to create an instance of a new derived class and initialize that new instance from a parent instance, then just create a constructor for the derived class that takes a previous parent instance as an argument and then implement the appropriate initialization logic in the constructor to copy data from the parent instance to your new derived child instance.

Comment: Otherwise, a derived instance IS a parent instance also so you don't extend an existing parent instance INTO a child instance.  While, you can probably hack that kind of stuff in Javascript, it's not what you should be doing as its a messy model with all sorts of ways for things to fail.   Instead, create the object instance you want (the desired child class) and give it whatever data you want it to initialize itself from as a constructor argument.

Comment: No idea what this means: "Is it possible to carry the state of the instance over from parent to child, not just the constructor functions."

Comment: No idea what this means: "I know that I can instantiate directly to the child, however just wondering if I can extend once the parent calls it."

Comment: i mean like if I was to call from inside the initialized class const child = new Child(this)

Comment: Yes, you can do this `const child = new Child(this)` as long as the `Child` constructor expects an object that matches the type of object that `this` represents and probably that that object pointed to by `this` is fully initialized (not in the middle of its own constructor).

Comment: Also, remember that in Javascript when you have a derived class such as your Purchase and Transaction and you instantiate the child class such as Purchase, you are getting ONE object that has properties and methods that belong to both Purchase and Transaction.  It's not like there's a Transaction object and a separate Purchase object.  There's one Purchase object that contains the combined set of properties/methods for both the Purchase and Transaction functionality.  One object.

Comment: The thing is Its much more complex then I put forward. whatever, Im just going to close this, and make second classes, that are made from inside the original -> and then save the object that is derived from the second class that i made

Comment: Yeah, so kind of hard for us to help when you don't describe the whole problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 The OP’s asking about downcasting (extending) an instance of the superclass into the subclass’, preferably without copying.